# shell: prefixing output with spaces with paste

Tags: shell

A lot of time one needs to prefix 4 spaces to some shell output and transform it into valid markdown code. E.g. When posting a question or answer here on stackoverflow.

It's actually quite easy to do with `sed`:

```
some_command | sed -e 's/^/    /'
```

But I'd like to do it with `paste` if possible. Because `paste` takes 2 files as input, all I came up with was this:

```
some_command | paste 4_space_file -
```

where `4_space_file` is actually a file whose whole content was 4 spaces.

Is there a neater way to achieve this with `paste` without having an actual file on the hard drive?

Comment: What do you do if your `4_space_file` isn't the same length as the output from `some_command`? Also, what are you doing about the tab character that `paste` inserts? (Which is to say: I'm questioning the presumption, embedded in this question, that `paste` is an appropriate tool for the job at hand).

Answer (score 3):

#### Literal Answers Using Paste

First, to answer your literal question:

```
some_command | paste <(printf '    \n') -
```

...yields the same output as passing `paste` the name of a file with a single line having four spaces and a newline as its content. **However, the output from `paste` in this case is *not* four-character indents for each line; the first line has four spaces and a tab prepended, subsequent lines are prefixed with only a tab.**

If you wanted to generate an input of the appropriate length while still using `paste`, then you'd end up with something uglier. Say (with bash 4.0 or newer):

```
ls | {
   mapfile -t lines                              # read output from ls into an array

   # our answer, here, is to move to three spaces in the input, and use paste -d' ' to
   # ...add a fourth space during processing.
   paste -d' ' \
       <(yes '   ' | head -n "${#lines[@]}") \
       <(printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}")
}
```

`<()` is [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax, which expands to a filename which, when read from, will yield the output from the code contained.

---

#### Better Answers

For a native bash approach, you might also consider defining a function:

```
ident4() { while IFS= read -r line; do printf '    %s\n' "$line"; done; }
```

...for later use:

```
some_command | indent4
```

Unlike `paste`, this actually inserts *exactly* four spaces (with no intervening tab) on *every* line, for the exact number of lines in your input (no need to synthesize the correct length).

---

Also consider `awk`:

```
awk '{ print "    " $0; }'
```